# HIKVISION, NVR configuration

Tags: hikvision

I own a HIKVISION CCTV system that includes the NVR model DS-7616NXI-42. I have successfully configured intelligent intrusion detection on the NVR, and it generates alerts that I can monitor through my HIK-Connect app.

However, I have encountered an issue where the system generates alerts at all times, even when it is unnecessary because we are aware that there are people present in the venue. Nevertheless, there are periods when the venue is unoccupied, and during those times, we activate the alarm system to provide additional protection.

My question is: Is it possible to connect the NVR with the alarm system in a way that the NVR sends alerts only when permitted by the alarm system? By "permits," I mean when the alarm system supplies +12V on any line or opens/closes any circuit.

To clarify, I cannot utilize an "Arming schedule" as we do not follow a fixed schedule in our setting.

I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions you may have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a solution called "one key disarming," which involves utilizing the Alarming inputs/sockets located on the back wall of the NVR.

There is a helpful video demonstrating how to use this feature, which can be found at the following link: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPawyIPTxr0)

Although the video does not explicitly mention it, setting up "one key disarming" resolves the issue with intelligent detection.